# How to compare milliseconds in MySQL with a given date

Tags: mysql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

Using

```
mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.45, for redhat-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 5.0
```

I have a table defined like this:

```
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                    | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI |         |       | 
| user_id               | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL |         |       | 
| directory_id          | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL |         |       | 
| attribute_name        | varchar(255) | NO   |     |         |       | 
| attribute_value       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| attribute_lower_value | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Selecting the attribute_value for my last authenticated time returns

```
+-------------------+-----------------+
| attribute_name    | attribute_value |
+-------------------+-----------------+
| lastAuthenticated | 1330380013284   | 
+-------------------+-----------------+
```

If I verify the value using http://www.epochconverter.com/ it says

```
Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds:
GMT: Mon, 27 Feb 2012 22:00:13 GMT
```

But if I try the following line of code

```
mysql> select from_unixtime('1330380013284');
+--------------------------------+
| from_unixtime('1330380013284') |
+--------------------------------+
| NULL                           | 
+--------------------------------+
```

Anyone who immediately knows what I'm missing here?

Comment: +1 for being very clear. but the aswer is easy :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to divide by 1000 as well as remove the quotes, otherwise your dates are way off

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(theField/1000);

SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1330380013284/1000);
```

See the documentation - notice the MySQL methods return SECONDS, not milliseconds like you are using:

[MySQL docs for UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

```
If called with no argument, returns a Unix timestamp 
(SECONDS since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC) as an unsigned integer
```

Comment: Ahh, tnx! Yet another case of me not having RTFM :-)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `'`, you have to pass a number.