# Format MySQL timestamp to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am given a MySQL 12 digit TimeStamp (253402214400) to format it in `mm/dd/yyyy` without using any language. Database field is type of longtext and here is what I am doing.

`SELECT time_stamp;`  returns `253402214400`

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time_stamp,'%m/%d/%Y');`  returns `NULL`

`SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(time_stamp);` also returns `NULL`

`SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_stamp);` returns `0`

I don't know what type of `Timestamp` is this, but please help me to format it in `mm/dd/yyyy`.

`Thanks`

Comment: `253402214400` is not a valid timestamp.

Comment: @HamedKamrava Yes, it was in milliseconds. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sorry everybody, I think the time was givin in `milliseconds`, so by some research I could reach here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9483289/750302 and resolved it with `DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_stamp/1000), '%m/%d/%Y');` [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93a575/2)! ...

> `Thank You Everyone for your Support!`

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_stamp), '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Example:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2016-05-01 09:23:00', '%d/%m/%Y') // result: 01/05/2016
```

Comment: Returns `Null`, because as I said `FROM_UNIXTIME(time_stamp);` retruns `NULL`.

Comment: FROM_UNIXTIME returns the NULL because it expects the time-stamp in milliseconds, but if you have the timestamp like '2016-05-01 09:23:00' just use it in DATE_FORMAT() function. I modified the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can Try Like this

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_stamp), '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Returns NULL because FROM_UNIXTIME(time_stamp) retruns NULL